# DevEcoStudio - Huawei Login: Failed to sign the Agreement

Tags: huawei-developers, harmonyos, huawei-account, deveco-studio

Hello Huawei Developers,

While trying to run a simulator for a HarmoyOS project in DevEcoStudio, I need to do a Huawei login and sign in with Huawei developer credentials.

Ideally, it should log in with the username/password passed and show the list of available simulators but it fails with error - **"Failed to sign the Agreement"**.

Steps, I am following to login to do Huawei Login from - 
*DevEcoStudio-> Main Menu -> Tools -> Device Manager -> Login -> Login in browser*

I have tried the same with 2 different sets of credentials but saw the same error. Here is the screenshot attached for the same.

[image]

**NOTE: Explicitly login with the same credentials is not failing for sign in. It is failing only if I try to login from DevEcoStudio**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, There was some issue from the server-side, and it fixed auto. Now, it is running fine.